# Error while accessing array of String. (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException)

Tags: android

In my code i have Array of String variable stored in a class statically. While trying to access the string in another class this error occurs. I cant find the reason and solution for this. Can any one please help me on this.

Here is my code

Module.java

```
        static String[] myLogoName = new String[] { "one",
        "two", "three", "four","five", "six" };
```

Sample.java

```
    String tempLogo = "three";
private boolean checkLogoimage(String filePath) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Modules.myLogoName.length - 1; i++) {
        if (Modules.myLogoName[i] == tempLogo) {
            LogoVal = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

while debugging this error occurs and while Running eventhough the value is in the string it is not showing that...

Edited:

This is the error that occurs while debugging..

```
03-23 19:40:12.807: E/jdwp(12074): REQ: UNSUPPORTED (cmd=2/11 dataLen=8 id=0x000e08)
```

Note: there is no error while running.

Thanks,
Regards, Sniper

Comment: No way this code could have caused that exception. Look more carefully at the stack trace -- it'll tell you what line caused the problem. If it doesn't make sense to you, show us, and we'll understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `if (Modules.myLogoName[i] == tempLogo)` , try  if `(Modules.myLogoName[i].equals( tempLogo))`
Maybe the error is happening because you are trying to compare memory references instead of values, and static variables are stored in application heap.

Comment: Nope. I don't think so. It is UnsupportedOperation.